# Updating Multiple TextView in layout with data from json respose

Tags: android, textview

I want to populate multiple Text Views in layout with JSON data.
I'm getting JSON data but Text View's text is not updated.
Need help!

Here is my code.

```
JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result1);

        JSONArray json_profile_image = response.optJSONArray("profile_image");


        for (int i = 0; i < json_profile_image.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jsonObject1 = json_profile_image.getJSONObject(i);
            String first_name = jsonObject1.getString("firstname").toString();
            String middle_name = jsonObject1.getString("middlename").toString();
            String last_name = jsonObject1.getString("lastname").toString();


            lbl_firstname.setText(first_name);
            lbl_middlename.setText(middle_name);
            lbl_lastname.setText(last_name);

        }
```

Comment: this way you only get last datas in the textviews. better go with a listview and supply the datas to adapter and get the work done.

Comment: actually I want that data to update details of user's profile, it will be hard to update listview data(i.e. to identify which field is updated)

Comment: Did you update the textviews inside UI-thread? You should log the first_name, middle_name and last_name to make sure you got the correct data.

Comment: I'm getting correct data. If I try to setText() for a single TextView then it works corectly, but while using multiple TextView I got a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a solution!

I first created an arraylist-

```
ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

then added values from json to it-

```
dataList.add(first_name);
dataList.add(middle_name);
dataList.add(last_name);
```

And then updated Text Views -

```
if(!dataList.isEmpty()){
    lbl_firstname.setText(dataList.get(0));
    lbl_middlename.setText(dataList.get(1));
    lbl_lastname.setText(dataList.get(2));
}
```

Since I used AsyncTask to get data in json from url, I updated Text Views in

```
onPostExecute()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create textview dynamically inside the for loop as below

```
for (int i = 0; i < json_profile_image.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject jsonObject1 = json_profile_image.getJSONObject(i);
        String first_name = jsonObject1.getString("firstname").toString();
        String middle_name = jsonObject1.getString("middlename").toString();
        String last_name = jsonObject1.getString("lastname").toString();
LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
TextView tv=new TextView(this);
tv.setLayoutParams(lparams);
tv.setText(first_name);
yourLinearLayout.addView(tv);
}
```

create textview for all json objects

Comment: Sorry but I cannot create TextView dynamically because of design issues.